# What's the meaning of "in [...] respect"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

*fundamentally* is defined on Google as:

> 1 - in central or primary respects.
>   *two fundamentally different concepts of democracy*
>
> - used to make an emphatic statement about the basic truth of something.
>     *fundamentally, this is a matter for doctors*

In the first definition, what does *in [...] respect* mean of *in central or primary respects*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In [...] respect* means in a particular aspect or in a particular way we consider the matter.

> **[respect](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20respect)**
>   <sup>noun</sup>
>   2. a particular aspect, point, or detail.

In general, we can consider the same thing (or the matter at hand) in many respects, i.e. from different viewpoints. Just like the story of *[Blind men and an elephant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_men_and_an_elephant)*, where the blinds who feel the elephant in different parts (such as the head, an ear, the trunk, a foot, etc.) would have different opinions on what an elephant would look like.

Comment: I actually came across this word from this passage: [When critics fret that tablets on every Applebee’s table are going to *fundamentally* ruin our ability to sit down and talk to each other over a meal, they’re pining for an experience that is already, in many ways, gone.](http://www.salon.com/2013/12/04/dont_panic_about_applebees_tablets_at_tables_wont_destroy_human_interaction/). So I'm guessing in this case, both definitions of *fundamentally* provided by Google could apply to the term used in this passage?

Comment: I agree. Usually, I understand it (*fundamentally*) the same way I understand *basically*, or *essentially*.